# Effectively Click on an option javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm using

> document.getElementById("order").value ="it";

To select an option from something like

```
<option value="AT">AUSTRIA</option>
<option value="BY">BELARUS</option>
<option value="BE">BELGIUM</option>
<option value="BG">BULGARIA</option>
<option value="HR">CROATIA</option>
```

The problem is that when I click it with the mouse I get the option and the website shows me other information like the price the shipping for that country etc.

But when I'm using this code `( document.getElementById("order").value ="it";)` I select the country, but the sites don't "understand" I have to select that country so it doesn't show me the shipping for that country etc.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try also dispatching a `change` and/or `input` event on the `select` element.

Comment: how i can do that ?

Comment: I just added an answer for u, please tell me if it works as expected. Btw, welcome to Stack Overflow.